# Java process killed due to out of memory after running job in container for an hour

Tags: docker, circleci

I have setup a job for running automation tests in CircleCI (https://hub.docker.com/r/jiteshsojitra/docker-headless-vnc-container), it works fine but after running tests for an hour it reaches to memory limit and suddenly kills running Java/ant job. So is there any way to increase the container memory so tests can be ran for 5-6 hours in container or its paid feature?

I tried by putting `- JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m` in YAML script but overall container memory size reaches to ~4GB as it looks like.

## References:

```
https://circleci.com/gh/jiteshsojitra/zm-selenium/231
https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/jiteshsojitra/zm-selenium/231/output/106/0?file=true
```

## Log trail:

```
BUILD FAILED
/headless/zm-selenium/build.xml:348: Java returned: 137

Total time: 76 minutes 26 seconds
Exited with code 137

Hint: Exit code 137 typically means the process is killed because it was running out of memory
Hint: Check if you can optimize the memory usage in your app
Hint: Max memory usage of this container is 4286337024
according to /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max_usage_in_bytes
```

Comment: See my remarks to fiskeben about the larger machines available in CircleCI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this problem. [It is a limit in CircleCI (or the VM, really)](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/oom/). Only solution is to make your app use less memory.

Comment: What size machine are you using? The default machine size is 4G, and 8G upgrades are available (either in the Docker or Machine types).

Comment: 4G only - I wasn't aware of 8G machines.

Comment: Yep. If you're a paid customer you can request an upgrade on [Docker executors](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#resource_class), looks like they've added 16G since I last checked! Also, if you are a paid or free customer, you can use [a machine executor](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/), which has 8G. That's free for the time being, but is a bit slower than the Docker equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

fiskeben is right. I think your mentioned container is an fork of our [consol/docker-headless-vnc-container](https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container) image. So you can add in the startup script the following lines.

```
# set correct java startup
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Duser.home=$HOME -Xmx${JVM_HEAP_XMX}m"
# add docker jvm flags, can maybe removed with JDK9
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"
```

Now you would be able to set the environment variable `JVM_HEAP_XMX` with amount of megabytes your JVM should use, e.g.

```
docker run -e JVM_HEAP_XMX=512 ...
```

If you want to determine the size dynamically take a look at that script [jvm_options.sh](https://github.com/ConSol/sakuli/blob/master/docker/sakuli-client/src/common/scripts/jvm_options.sh).